# TFS 2012 hide content of work item field based on rights

Tags: tfs, hide

is there a way to hide the content of a field based on a role?

I thought about creating a serverside plugin which empties the field if the user does not have permission to view the field and repopulate it on save. But I don't know how to do this, I did not find any event which I could use. Any idea?

My first intent was to use the EMPTY rule but this really clears the content and does not repopulate it. Also the READONLY rule is not acceptable for us. Do you have any idea?

I know this was already requested http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2088177-add-ability-to-hide-mask-fields-in-a-work-item-bas but I need the functionality now.

I also thought about creating a workitem where the hidden fields are stored in and linking it to the other work item but this is not the solution I want ...

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is by creating a custom work item control. That control can then only display the contents of the value if the user has the correct permissions. What it does not prevent though is to see/update the data via other tools like Excel, Work Item Query or Bulk Update.

As the suggestion on User Voice suggests, it is not possible today in TFS. So please vote and make sure the Team Foundation Server team knows it is high priority for a lot of our customers.

Ewald Hofman (Program Manager, Team Foundation Server)

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2013 when u use the Empty Rule, the field disappear! You can see that in Scrum Template when you change de WIT state to Done the Remaining Work field are hidden

Comment: thanks for your post. The problem is, that the Remaining Work field is also cleared (the content is deleted). I only wanted to hide the field ...